# Can't initialise packed array of rational numbers

Tags: packed-arrays

If I evaluate the following code

```
t = Developer`ToPackedArray[{0, 2/7, -(1/7)}];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[t]
```

Mathematica returns `False`.

Is there any way that I can pack an array of rational numbers?

Comment: No, packed arrays can obly be used for _machine precision reals_ (64 bit floats, a.k.a. doubles), _machine precision complex numbers, and for _machine integers (64 bit integers).

Comment: You can't. [See the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/ToPackedArray.html) - it says _Possible types are: Integer, Real, and Complex._ . `FullForm[2/7]` is `Rational[2,7]` so it won't work. You either use reals / complex (machine) numbers, or you have two lists of integers, one for the numerator, one for the denominator, or have a list of pairs of integers.

Comment: Ow, I couldn't find the docs on packedarray because I looked for Packed Array in the documentation center and it only returned some info about packed array as a datatype for compiled functions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. [See the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/ToPackedArray.html) - it says *Possible types are: Integer, Real, and Complex*. If you check `FullForm[2/7]` it gives `Rational[2,7]` so it won't work.

So you either use reals / complex (machine) numbers, or you have two lists of integers, one for the numerator, one for the denominator, or have a list of pairs of integers.

---

Here's how you can pack a list of pairs of `{numerator, denominator}`  instead since you are allowed to pack integers:

```
t = Developer`ToPackedArray[NumeratorDenominator[{0, 2/7, -(1/7)}]]
Developer`PackedArrayQ[t]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Bear in mind: _Only machine-sized numbers can be stored in packed form_ so I think there will be a limit on how large a magnitude those numerators/denominators can have.

Comment: ... and that will be any number allowed from min -2^63 to max 2^63 - 1 apparently (on a 64 bit machine).

Comment: If you could add the comment (it can't be done) to your answer I will mark it as correct.